# Nested loop bug - java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to solve this leetcode challenge, but it's failing 3 tests. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
public int findContentChildren(int[] greed, int[] size) {

    if (size.length == 0 || greed.length == 0) return 0;

    int satisfied = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < greed.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size.length; j++) {
            if (greed[i] <= size[j]) {
                satisfied++;
                size[j] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return satisfied;
}
```

"Assume you are an awesome parent and want to give your children some cookies. But, you should give each child at most one cookie. Each child i has a greed factor gi, which is the minimum size of a cookie that the child will be content with; and each cookie j has a size sj. If sj >= gi, we can assign the cookie j to the child i, and the child i will be content. Your goal is to maximize the number of your content children and output the maximum number. 
Note:
You may assume the greed factor is always positive. 
You cannot assign more than one cookie to one child.

Example 1:

Input: [1,2,3], [1,1]

Output: 1

Explanation: You have 3 children and 2 cookies. The greed factors of 3 children are 1, 2, 3.

And even though you have 2 cookies, since their size is both 1, you could only make the child whose greed factor is 1 content.
You need to output 1."

https://leetcode.com/problems/assign-cookies/

Comment: What kind of cookies are involved here?  Chocolate chip, gingerbread men, something else?

Comment: Please add link to the question

Comment: @AdityaGupta Added :)

Comment: @taralee98 What is your error? Do you get a timeout?

Comment: Leetcode usually provides a test case that is failing your algorithm. In future you could attach that too to get exact answers rather than generic answers. Cheers and upvoted for adding your code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I found missing in your code.

You are trying all cookies for a child. This is done until one cookie satisfies the child. Although the cookie is marked as -1, the amortized time is high because the checks on -1 will still be made again. Ideally, this check should be avoided since the cookie is already used.

Secondly, you may not match the `perfect cookie` if the arrays are not sorted. Reason is present in other answers here.

Marking used cookie as `-1` was a clever move, but is not required for this question. Your runtime is O(nm), but could be done in O(n) by iterating both the sorted arrays together and maintaining he pointers to read child and last used cookie.

Time complexity is calculated excluding the sorting part.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through the cookies and children in order that they appear, not a sorted order. If you have cookies 1, 2, 3 and children 3, 2, 1, you'll only match two cookies when you actually have a perfect match. You need to sort the arrays or use a data structure like a heap in order to maximize the cookie distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the two arrays.

```
Arrays.sort(greed);
Arrays.sort(size);
```

Suppose greed is [4,5] and size is [5,4] in the example you have quoted above. Without sorting (per your logic), only one child can be satisfied, but with sorting, you can satisfy both the children.

Comment: Suppose greed is [4,5] and size is [5,4] in the example you have quoted above. Without sorting (per your logic), only one child can be satisfied, but with sorting, you can satisfy both the children.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other answers. You need to sort both the arrays before running the for loop. For better clarity I have made changes at the exact place , where they need to be.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public int findContentChildren(int[] greed, int[] size) {
        int satisfied = 0;
    Arrays.sort(greed);
    Arrays.sort(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < greed.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size.length; j++) {
            if (greed[i] <= size[j]) {
                satisfied++;
                size[j] = 0;
                //greed[i]=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return satisfied;
    }
}
```

changes are :

```
import java.util.*;
```

and then sort both the arrays before using the for loop.

```
Arrays.sort(greed);
Arrays.sort(size);
```

Also since satisfied value is initialized at 0 only we dont need to do a boundary condition return. Hence the below check is removed

```
if (size.length == 0 || greed.length == 0) return 0;
```